# How come these two alerts showing the height and offsetheight of the same element don't display the same number?

Tags: javascript, html

the alerts are as follows:

```
alert(document.getElementById("col_st_scroll").offsetHeight);
alert(document.getElementById("col_st_scroll").style.height);
```

now, the col_st_scroll element is fully visible in the web browser, shouldn't that mean offsetHeight and style.height should returnt he same value?

problem solved. The element was resized by another function in the time it took to click ok ont he first alert.

Comment: Just for fun, see what `window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('col_st_scroll'),null).getPropertyValue('height');` height returns. Whatever that produces is the browser-rendered 'real' value.

Comment: @DavidThomas that returns the same value 'alert(document.getElementById("col_st_scroll").style.height);' gets

Answer (score 1):

This is from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetHeight):

> Typically, an element's offsetHeight is a measurement which includes the element borders, the element vertical padding, the element horizontal scrollbar (if present, if rendered) and the element CSS height.

The `style.height` property represents the content height only (assuming you're on "strict" rendering mode, not "quirks").

Comment: The problem is offsetHeight returns 400 where i'm using it while I can clearly see (i enabled borders to check) that it's way more than that (520 or something). So it's not about a few pixels from borders and padding, it's a 120px difference.

Comment: And there's no `padding` also? Could you create a jsfiddle including the CSS?

Comment: nevermind, the problem was that between the first and 2nd alerts the element was resized by another function. thanks for the help.